# Validation error while posting xml request with DOCTYPE in asp .net core web api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a simple API endpoint with POST method. I am passing request in XML format and it works fine when XML does not contain DOCTYPE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<name x="5" y="5">M1P1</name>
```

And it fails when the request is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE nta PUBLIC '-//Uppaal Team//DTD Flat System 1.1//EN' 'http://www.it.uu.se/research/group/darts/uppaal/flat-1_2.dtd'>
<name x="5" y="5">M1P1</name>
```

Erro message :

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|bda6cf88-4cc4b4a778aae158.",
    "errors": {
        "": [
            "An error occurred while deserializing input data."
        ]
    }
```

My service configuration in Startup.cs is :

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
            }).AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
              .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
```

Schema and post method are as follows :

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "name")]
    public class Name
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "x")]
        public string X { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "y")]
        public string Y { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<Name> Transform(Name name)
        {
            return name;
        }
```

Target Framework is .NET Core 3.1

Any help/explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The contract is using XML Serialization along with an XmlReader.  The reader has to be set to ignore DTD processing.

Comment: Does it mean that I should write a custom serializer instead of using the standard one or Is there a way that we can ignore DTD processing? I did a google search but couldn't find any solution. Could you direct me to some documentation? Thanks

Comment: I haven't found any good documentation.  You don't need a custom serialize just a custom XmlSerializerInputFormatter.  I only found custom Inputformatter for text not xml. Although the two should be similar.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: How do you post the Xml request? Can you share the related code to reproduce the problem? Besides, you could consider to check the XML document content before sending the xml request, and detect whether it contains the DOCTYPE or not, if find it, try to remove it, then send the xml request.

Comment: I am using Postman and using the xml mentioned in the question in the body of the request. Actually the request is coming from third-party and do not have access to prevent DOCTYPE before request is received.